# How to apply background image in css html

Tags: html, css

Good day everyone! I am trying apply a background image via an image link but I do not know how to make it work. Does anyone know how to make this code works. Thank you.

```
background-image: url("https://www.logodesign.net/logo/building-on-crescent-4303ld.png? 
                   size=2&industry=company")
```

Comment: That looks like CSS code. How are you including it in your page?

Comment: checkout for info about the css code https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-image.asp . Also check if it actually gets applied in the browser inspector.

Comment: Show the whole CSS and HTML too. Did you apply it to a class, id or a tag type? Note: because of the word wrapping there are some spaces before the size part in your css, remove these.

Answer (score 1):

You are not supposed to use HTML for setting a background image. You should learn css.
But here is an example if you want a taste:

```
<div class="your-class">
<style>
  .your-class{
    height: 500px;
    width: 500px;
    background-image:url("https://www.logodesign.net/logo/building-on-crescent-4303ld.png?size=2&industry=company");
    background-size:cover;
  }
</style>
```

Answer (score -2):

Instead of exporting via html, you can do it with css operations.

Comment: The code in the question **is** CSS. The question is asking how to use it.